# Use align with flex

Tags: html, css

I want to use the property of align in div element. But as I have given flex property to both this element and parent element so align does not work.

What could be a alternative?

Comment: Show use a part of your code with proper CSS styles

Comment: there are many options for alignment in flex containers.  See [https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added `flex` property to both the parent and child element, you can use the `align-items` and `justify-content` property to align the child element.

Here is a [complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  border: dashed 2px black;
}

.box div {
  display: flex;
   width:200px;
  height:200px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

.box div p{
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: dotted 2px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without using the <p> tag. Text is directly in the div section

Comment: Its not necessary to use the <p> tag, that's just for demo purposes. You can check out the mentioned css-tricks blog, it gives you a brief description. If you found this answer insightful, kindly upvote it.